# IdentityRole Navigational Property Exception Using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having an issue mapping the "IdentityRole" property to my ApplicationUsers class. I am receiving an error to the effect of:

++++

```
The declared type of navigation property WebApp.Core.DAL.ApplicationUsers.IdentityRoles is not     compatible with the result of the specified navigation.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: The declared type of navigation property WebApp.Core.DAL.ApplicationUsers.IdentityRoles is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation. 

Source Error: 


Line 28:             using (CMSContext cntx = new CMSContext())
Line 29:             {
Line 30:                 var users = cntx.Users
Line 31:                                 .Include(m => m.IdentityRoles)
Line 32:                                 .Include(s => s.AspNetUsersSites)

Source File: c:\LocalSites\WebApp\1.0.0.0\DAL\UserManagement\User.cs    Line: 30 

Stack Trace: 


[MetadataException: The declared type of navigation property     WebApp.Core.DAL.ApplicationUsers.IdentityRoles is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation. ]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ValidateNavPropertyOp(PropertyOp op) +401
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(PropertyOp op, Node n) +80
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n) +163
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitScalarOpDefault(ScalarOp op, Node n) +33
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n) +163
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n) +22
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitAncillaryOpDefault(AncillaryOp op, Node n) +21
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n) +163
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n) +22
           System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitAncillaryOpDefault(AncillaryOp op, Node n) +21
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n) +163
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n) +599
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n) +163
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n) +22
       System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n) +21
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys) +106
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo, Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys) +54
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets) +236
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) +441
```

++++

I have lazy loading off and my ApplicationUsers class looks like this

```
namespace WebApp.Core.Contracts
{
    public class ApplicationUsers : IdentityUser
    {
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string LockoutReason { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AspNetUsersSites> AspNetUsersSites { get; set; }

    // a collection of roles that can be written to, since it needs to be evaluated earlier before it's disposed of
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual List<IdentityRole> IdentityRoles { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUsers> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here          
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public async Task<IList<string>> GenerateUserRolesAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUsers> manager, string userId)
    {
        var userRoles = await manager.GetRolesAsync(this.Id);
        return userRoles;
    }

    public async Task DeleteUser(UserManager<ApplicationUsers> manager, string username)
    {
        var user = manager.FindByName(username);            
        await manager.DeleteAsync(user);
    }                
}
```

My Linq query looks like this

```
 public static List<Contracts.ApplicationUsers> GetUsersForSiteWithRoles(int SiteID){
        using (CMSContext cntx = new CMSContext())
        {
            var users = cntx.Users
                            .Include(m => m.IdentityRoles)
                            .Include(s => s.AspNetUsersSites)
                            .Where(i => i.AspNetUsersSites.Where(s => s.SiteID == SiteID).Count() > 0).ToList();

            return users;
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with the navigational property I added and/or the query. All I am really trying to do is return users with their roles that are stored in my database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it should be:

```
public virtual ICollection<IdentityRole> IdentityRoles { get; set; }
```

Not `List<IdentityRole>`.

Second, this relationship already exists on `ApplicationUser` through inheritance from `IdentityUser` in  the `Roles` property. You're creating a secondary relationship here that will never be used by the Identity framework.

Also, for what it's worth, if you want your `AspNetUserSites` to follow the table name scheme of the Identity tables, you need only specify the `Table` attribute on the class. Naming your class in this way is obtuse. For example:

```
[Table("AspNetUserSites")]
public class Site
{
    ...
}
```

Then you just have a nice class like `Site` instead of `AspNetUserSite`

**UPDATE**

`IdentityUserRole` is just the join table between `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`. In the default implementation there's not a whole lot of point in its existence, but you could potentially extend the Identity classes to attach additional information on the relationship that way.

Anyways, if you just want to get at the actual `IdentityRoles`, just do something like:

```
var roleIds = user.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).ToList();
var roleNames = db.Roles.Where(r => roleIds.Contains(r.Id)).Select(r => r.Name);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Chris. I am definitely new to ASP.NET Identity and to entity framework in general. I have looked into this and I can see that an instance of ApplicationUser has a ".Roles" property. But this property contains a collection of "IdentityUserRole". And all this seems to contain is the role id and not the role name. Is there anyway to get a collection of roles that has both roleid and name?

Comment: Essentially, what I am trying to accomplish is to take an instance of a user and then loop through their IdentityRoles and write out the name of the role to the screen. It seems to me (based on my limited understanding), that I cannot access the name of the role through the user instance. Is this correct?